# Is there other programs like JRebel?

Tags: java, jrebel

Well, I use JRebel every day for the server I own, I love the ability of adding new features and never having to restart the server. Now that JRebel social is gone, is their other free alternatives to JRebel that do the exact same thing JRebel does? For Java 7+

Comment: JRebel Social isn't gone. It is migrated to my.jrebel.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider to use this:
[Dynamic Code Evolution VM](http://ssw.jku.at/dcevm/)

I've used it a little when it was with Java 6 I guess, have no idea whether it works with Java 7 as well though

Comment: I was looking for something for Java 7+.

Comment: DCEVM works with Java 7 too. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998669/redeploy-alternatives-to-jrebel/7999973#7999973

Comment: Also have a look at [HotswapAgent](https://github.com/HotswapProjects/HotswapAgent), it builds on DCEVM to create something similar to JRebel