# dcevm true Hot Swap in Java vs JRebel/LiveRebel stability

Tags: java, jrebel, dcevm

I just [installed](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/07/get-true-hot-swap-in-java-with-dcevm-and-intellij-idea/) [DCEVM](http://dcevm.github.io/) on my dev machine with [hotswap agent](http://www.hotswapagent.org/quick-start) and it seems to work well.
DCEVM looks like an alternative to JRebel/LiveRebel. Also on production systems.

Is DCEVM and hotswap agent production ready?

What are the production-problematic issues?

Comment: AFAIK, DCEVM (or HotSwap agent) is not officially "production safe". Nevertheless, it's a very good and _free_ alternative to JRebel. More info also in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998669/redeploy-alternatives-to-jrebel).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both DCEVM and JRebel are meant for development environments only.

DCEVM works fine in many use cases, it can load most of the class changes and is perfect if you are on budget and need basic reload capability. In comparison JRebel works with over 100 frameworks like Spring, Hibernate etc which configuration DCEVM is not able to reload.

Difference is also in support. While DCEVM is community supported on as is basis then commercial JRebel has professional support team to help you with any trouble you might have.

Comment: LiveRebel has been developed for production environments. But they discontinued the product.

Comment: It should also be noted that DCEVM cannot reload static objects and values. For that, you have to restart the VM. I don't know how JRebel handles this in that regard.

Comment: ++ for handeling static members.