# Tomcat Hot Deployment for new class files

Tags: java, tomcat

I have read about "autoDeploy" attribute to "true" in server.xml
but this hot deployment for tomcat is only works for existing method implementation. If there are new java/class files added then it would still have to restart the server.

I was wondering if there are any way to hot deploy with tomcat without restarting when adding new files.

Answer (score 1):

If this is for improving your productivity when developing java applications by saving time waiting for restarts JRebel is a good bet. It works out of the box and will seamlessly inject new code into your JVM without needing to restart and supports reloading the configuration of lots of popular libraries and frameworks. Its not cheap however at $475 per year per license.

https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/

Comment: I already read up on jrebel but I was wondering if there are any alternative like open source similar to jrebel, but free.

Comment: This question seems to have the answers you are looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998669/redeploy-alternatives-to-jrebel