# Is there a way to deploy a jar without restarting in Tomcat 9?

Tags: java, tomcat, jar

I know this question has came up before here, however this is in regards to tomcat 9.

Is there anything that has changed in latest tomcat releases that allows to deploy a jar file without restarting tomcat ? We have been using tomcat 7 in our development and all developers restarting tomcat has been time consuming. Its application that has 700 java files that gets built in to a .jar file and about 1000 jsp files that rely on those .jar file, we are not using war. Can WatchedResource be used for this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1390549/1927832 >

Comment: Have you considered [JRebel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37393783/tomcat-hot-depolyment-for-new-class-files)?

Comment: I am not an expert Tomcat user; but why don't you deploy a WAR; which can by nature be re-loaded without restarting tomcat?

Answer (score 1):

You can always restart your webapp and not your Tomcat instance as long as the JAR resides in `WEB-INF/lib` and not in `CATALINA_BASE/lib`.

Comment: I am not using war deploy , they are plain jsps and jars , so that wont work right ?

Comment: Same approach, you have an exploded app. Hit reload in Tomcat manager or via JMX.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Eclipse IDE, then you can simply use [FileSync](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/filesync) plugin to hot deploy the `.class` files into tomcat `WEB-INF/classes` folder.

Basically, you need to map `YOUR_PROJECT/target/classes` folder to `WEB-INF/classes` so that they will always be in sync.

This is what we do in our project to avoid the restarts of Tomcat because of source file changes.