# hybris java code change without server restart

Tags: java, tomcat7, sap-commerce-cloud

Is there any way to get the java code changed without hybris server restart. Its taking long time for each java code change and then server restart. Development time get increase and productivity decrease. One way is JRebel but that is license tool and evaluation version last till 15 days only. I am looking for any opensource tool or specific configuration to reflect java code changes without server restart.

I am using hybris 5.4.

As we know hybris server is hybris modified tomcat server.

Comment: Have a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998669/redeploy-alternatives-to-jrebel

Answer (score 0):

For hybris issues you can better ask the hybris-support.

Besides of that, as I developed in hybris I used JRebel, which worked very good. I dont know other helpful things for that. And yes, its annoying to restart the hybris at every codechange... but JRebel is a good solution.

Comment: yes I know JRebel is good but its licence one. This is not issue, I am just looking a solution for java code hot deployment on hybris server (hybris modified tomcat)

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using DCEVM (Dynamic Code Evolution VM) https://dcevm.github.io/
It does not offer all the features that JREBEL does but for me is extremely helpfull.

Please note that, from my knowledge, it is not compatible with JREBEL.

Answer (score 0):

We used "HotSwap" which was a functionality of Eclipse.  I believe Intellij has similar support.  This lets you change class methods in real time.

The downside is this only works in the body of methods.  You CANNOT alter a method's signature (ie Number of args, name, return type, etc) or create new classes.

But still better than nothing!

Answer (score 0):

You can try out jrebel, we have been successfully using jrebel for hot swap in Hybris, they also provide all the set up steps necessary for integrating jrebel to you environment.