# How to get user access in Hybris?

Tags: authentication, sap-commerce-cloud

I would like to know how I can get users login Access information and their login frequency from Hybris db. Is it possible to know the table/s where this kind of data is stored?

Thanks in advance,
AC

Comment: Have a look in this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998669/redeploy-alternatives-to-jrebel

Answer (score 0):

The only available information would be the last login date, if you want to keep more information about the login frequency, you will need to :

- Update the User or Employee model to add something like a collection of Date
- Customize the 'CockpitAuthenticationProvider' class to populate your new attribute whenever a cockpit user successfully login

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Benoit answer, you can write your custom logic in `StorefrontAuthenticationSuccessHandler` & `LoginAuthenticationFailureHandler` (based on success or failure) to save newly added attributes in User/Employee model.